# How to use arrow keys for navigation in PaneSelector, SlideView, and Slideshows?

Tags: user-interface

Clicking the tiny little buttons is difficult for the clumsy, it would be more reasonable to use arrows keys by default. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In the slideshow environment, in OS X at least, you can move back and forth between slides by pressing [page down] and [page up], respectively. By assigning [page down] and [page up] for this purpose, Wolfram Research made a better choice than arrow keys, which are better reserved for moving the insertion point.